# Web-storage with html pages

Tags: html, web-storage

I have created multiple html pages which i need to store using session storage (web storage) as in HTML5. I am not very clear what it is and how to implement it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

With [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) you can save data within your browser. There are several storage locations available which can be accessed through a javascript interface as described in the document.

What interface you choose (sessionStorage, localStorage) depends on the lifecycle of your data. E.g. do you need the data to be available only while the session is open (user is logged in)? Or do you want to save data for later visits as well?

One important thing to bear in mind is that older browsers do not support this, so especially older IE browsers won't be able to save the data.

Here's an example of using localStorage (which should be right for you, based on your comment below):

```
//save data
localStorage.setItem("indexName","Hello World");

//retrieve data
var value=localStorage.getItem("indexName");
```

You can use this in the document's beforeunload event to save data before the page is closed.

Comment: suppose i have few pages interlinked. I want to use local storage for the purpose that if the browser gets closed the same page gets opened. I know web storage can handle data but how can it be done for this purpse?

Comment: I added the answer in my post, hope that helps